# Python3: inheriting from list breaks automagically provided __ne__ when __eq__ is defined?

Tags: python, inheritance, python-3.x, super

In Python 3, if you provide an `__eq__` method, a sensible `__ne__` is also typically provided which makes use of your `__eq__`.  However, I have (in Python 3):

```
class SomeOtherClassWhichInheritsFromList(list):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.parval = 44

    def __eq__(self, other):
        print ("IN SomeOtherClassWhichInheritsFromList EQ")
        if isinstance(other, SomeOtherClassWhichInheritsFromList):
            return super().__eq__(other) and self.parval == other.parval
        return NotImplemented

class SomeClass(SomeOtherClassWhichInheritsFromList):
    def __init__(self, val):
        super().__init__()
        self.val = val

    def __eq__(self, other):
        print ("IN SomeClass EQ")
        if isinstance(other, SomeClass):
            return super().__eq__(other) and self.val == other.val
        return NotImplemented
```

And if I do:

```
sc = SomeClass(99)
sc2 = SomeClass(104)

print (sc != sc2)
```

I would expect to see:

```
IN SomeClass EQ
IN SomeOtherClassWhichInheritsFromList EQ
True
```

But I instead see:

```
False
```

Indicating that my `__eq__` isn't being called by the default provided `__ne__`.  If I change SomeOtherClassWhichInheritsFromList to inherit from object instead of list, it works as expected.

Is this because list does not seem to have an `__mro__` attribute, and thus all the `super()` stuff in my `__eq__` methods fails to get triggered?

Note: I know I could add my own `__ne__` method that calls my `__eq__` (which I'll have to do since I do want to inherit from list), but what I'm looking for here is an explanation of why I have to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you define `__eq__` you have to define `__ne__` as well, always.
From the "Data Model" documentation for Python 3.2:
"""There are no implied relationships among the comparison operators. The truth of x==y does not imply that x!=y is false. Accordingly, when defining **eq**(), one should also define **ne**() so that the operators will behave as expected.  """

[Python 3 Data Model](http://docs.python.org/release/3.2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__ne__)

What probably happen that you suppose that "In Python 3, if you provide an `__eq__` method, a sensible `__ne__` is also typically provided which makes use of your `__eq__`. " - is that `object`'s `__ne__` method does that. There is no reference to the behavior you state on the Data Model doc - although classes with no explicit superclass (therfore inheriting from `object`) behave as you describe.